# Problem installing OLETeX

Tags: windows, eps

I would like to embed [OLE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Linking_and_Embedding) objects as pictures into LaTeX documents.

The obvious choice is [OLETeX](http://oletex.sourceforge.net/).

However, I ran into problems installing the OLETeX Color PS L2 printer.

The OLETeX software seems to be a bit old as the documentation is in .hlp file format that is not supported anymore by modern Windows versions. I converted the .hlp file with [hlp2rtf](http://www.herdsoft.com/ftp/downloads.html#hlp2rtf) and I have found description for Windows 95/98 and Windows NT, this is an old piece of software indeed.

I downloaded a [driver](http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/detail.jsp?ftpID=1500) from [Adobe postscript printer driver page](http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/product.jsp?product=pdrv&platform=win). Upon starting the installer, I chose the directory OLETeX\PSPrint\Legacy and the printer OLETeX Color PS L2.

The OLETeX manual instructs me to look at the properties of the installed printer but it does not seem to be installed properly.

Did anybody succeed on using OLETeX, or, is this too old to work?

Also, should the above Adobe driver work on Windows 7?

Yes I see that this is slightly off-topic but the root of the problem is indeed about LaTeX.

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: I use Windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After help from @Peter Trifonov I was able to insert the picture of an OLE object into a pdf generated through LaTeX.

I had to download

http://www.wolf-s.homepage.t-online.de/wmf2eps/WMF2EPS.PPD-for-Win7.zip

which is an encapsulated postscript driver for Windows 7. Its README says

> Unpack this zip archive to any temporary directory
>
> Open Start|Control Panel|Printers.
>
> Click Add Printer in the Control Panel.
>
> Add a Local Printer, dont' care for the Printer Port (default is at LPT1:).
>
> For the Printer Driver, select Have Disk....
>
> Browse to your temporary Win7 subdirectory.
>
> Select W7Print.INF. This will install the printer WMF2EPS Color PS L2
>
> If the you already have installed another PS printer, the wizard asks 
>   you to replace the driver. You can keep the existing driver.
>
> Use the default setting for the standard-printer (not standard printer).
>
> Ignore the Warning for a missing didital signature.
>
> Printer Sharing: If you plan this computer to run as a license/print 
>   server, select Share as.. and type in a share name (e.g. WMF2EPSC). 
>   Please note that you'll need a site license for the shared license 
>   feature of WMF2EPS 1.3. For all other types of licenses: select Not Shared.
>
> No test page.
>
> The printer WMF2EPS Color PS L2 now appears in your printer list.

I followed the above and set the new printer output to EPS:

```
at WMF2EPS printer
   -> right click
      -> Printing settings
         -> Special
            -> Document settings
               -> PostScript settings
                  -> PostScript output settings
```

I have set Encapsulated PostScript (EPS).

And now came the crucial step: I had to restart Windows 7.

In OTEditor, I have selected the WMF2EPS printer at Options -> Conversion Settings, and then chose Options -> Save Settings.

I have printed an OLE object into the file `students.eps` using WMF2EPS. Then, running pdflatex on

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{oletex}

\begin{document}

\oleaddfile{OTCont2.otx}

\begin{figure}
\includeolepicture[angle=90]{students}
\caption{Excel table}\label{Demo version}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

yielded a pdf with a part of the original excel sheet selected in OTEditor.

That was the story so far.